# Possible $g(x)$ for an explicit solution of $u''-g(x) \times u =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am searching for the solution of the following ODE:

$$u''(x) - g(x) u(x) = 0  $$   $$\forall x\geq0 $$

with $g(x)$ being a positive function and $u(0) = a$ and $u'(0) = b$.
The question is then the following one:

For which specific function $g(x)$ do i have an explicit solution ?
The first obvious solution is when $g(x)=\lambda$ with $\lambda$ being a positive real but is there any other function for which an explicit solution exists ?

Comment: Do you consider special functions (Airy, Bessel, Dihedral, hypergeometric,...) as explicit?

Comment: yes as long as i have code to implement it and it runs fast enough

Comment: @LutzLehmann. I do not know what you think about but, from my point of view, *explicit* or *closed form* are becoming more and more elastic concepts. By the way, is the sine function a closed form or not ? Cheers :-)

Comment: your are right. IMHO, most of special functions are belonging to explicit ones as long as their numeric implementation is fast enough.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : The elementary or calculator functions have functional identities and simple differential equations and in result fast evaluation to maximally available accuracy over a large domain. For the special functions there is more resistance in the balance of accuracy and fast evaluation. CAS, especially Mathematica, have gotten better in applying the rules to simplify and solve ODE, but has there been much extension in the rules and tricks themselves in the last 50 years?